# LMM parameter estimation results differ when compared to OLS estimation

Tags: estimation, lme4-nlme

I am using lmer for estimating effect sizes and I am comparing the results with estimations obtained through OLS. I first ran the LMM model with simulated data where the effect sizes are known and I get in both cases correct estimations(lmm model estimation is the same as OLS estimations). However when I run some real data through the lmm model, I get for certain effects different answers between lmm and OLS.

Both techniques use the same designmatrices, yet i fail to understand  why I get different estimations between the two methods, is this normal?

Also, when I use the commands ranef on the lmm model, I obtain my random effects how do I verify that these are BLUPS?

Comment: Could you possibly have some oddness in the distribution of your actual data? Or perhaps the LMM estimation had an issue with convergence? The `ranef` function will return BLUPs as explained further here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111702/i-am-confused-with-ranef-function-in-r

Comment: No not really, I also scale and center the data in both situations. After that I plotted density plots of the  variables and I can't reall see anything weird

Comment: What is the random effect structure? Maybe that has an effect? (I'm grasping a bit since I could see a difference in a GLMM but not an LMM, but... maybe more information will ring a bell.)

Comment: I am not sure if understand what you are asking, do you want to know how the distribution of the random effects look like? I do get the following warning when I run the lmm model "fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient"

Comment: That error is probably the source of your problems.

Comment: Not sure, so far I haven't found an answer on how to deal with this, but I also get this error with the simulated data and the estimates there are the same as in OLS. I did take a look at the structure of the random effects and these seem off to me imgshare.io/image/Ny9wnY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to my simulated data and added on top of the created effects some noise(e ~N(0,1)). After that I calculated my estimators in both ways (OLS and via LMM) the estimators are no longer identical for the interaction and random effects. So the cause of the error is the noise.