# How to test whether changes in x track changes in y over multiple time points for multiple individuals

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

So I'm wondering how to analyse this data:

I have 30 people. for each person I have 2 normally distributed variables, x and y. I want to see whether x and y are linearly related, but 30 data points isn't that powerful. What might help is that I have x and y for each person over 5 consecutive weeks. So all in all 150 data points. I want to investigate whether changes in x track changes in y over the 5 weeks.

I feel like some sort of multilevel analysis/time series type model would work best, but searching for examples has not been fruitful.

Any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please expand the question to explain how you collected these data, what the data are, and whether there is expected to be a time effect and if so whether the time effect is expected to vary among `subjects`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by fitting a mixed effects model to these data. I wouldn't really call it *multilevel* as you don't appear to have grouping factors nested within each other. But this is just semantics and/or a matter of opinion. Clearly measurements are clustered within persons, so you could fit a model such as:

```
Y ~ X + (1|Subject)
```

and this will adjust the analysis for observations of one person being more similar to observations of the same person from week to week. i.e. to account for non-independence.

If `week` is purely a nuisance variable, then you could fit a crossed random effects model:

```
Y ~ X + (1|Subject) + (1|week)
```

This is crossed and not nested, since each observation "belongs" to one particular person, but that person does *not* "belong" to a particular week, and the same applies in vice-versa - an observation also "belongs" to a particular week, but that *week* does not "belong" to a particular person. More about crossed vs nested random effects can be [found here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified/228814#228814)

If the variance at the `week` level is sufficiently small you could remove it, applying the principle of parsimony, and go back the previous model. A likelihood ratio test could inform this, though clinical/expert domain knowledge should have the last say. This of course does not rule out the possibility of a *systematic' effect of `week`.

If there is systematic effect of `week` , then you could also consider either

```
Y ~ X + week + (1|Subject)
```

or

```
Y ~ X + week + (week|Subject)
```

to allow the "effect" of `week` to vary across each `Subject`.

Noting that you have 5 `week` points, you could code `week` as a factor, which could potentially uncover non-linearities, though the first of these it would provide 4 coefficient estimates, rather than 1 if you include it as continuous. In the 2nd model including `week` as a factor would also increase the number of random effects considerably, which could impede model convergence (especially as you have a small dataset) and also impede interpretation. That is, the data may not support that random structure.

There is also the option to allow the effect of `X` to vary across each `Subject`, for example:

```
Y ~ X + week + (X + week|Subject)
```

Note that in a regression model such as this, `X` is considered to be fixed, while Y is random - that means there should be no (or negligibly small) measurement error in `X`. If the situation is reversed then the dependent variable should be `X`. However if both variables are measured with error then it may be necessary to look at *mixed effects model with errors in variables*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I wouldn't expect a systematic effect of week on Y, I mainly wanted to include it to increase power of detecting a relationship between X and Y by adding more data points (i.e. including data from all 5 weeks means 5 times more data points than if i only analysed 1 week, which I hope gives me more power). I would expect that X varies with week. Would my power in this case be higher than if I just used ran analyses on a single week?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However, since you say that `X` and `week` are correlated, you should not fit random intercepts for `week` (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66161)). The first or third model in my answer would be the way to go. How strong is the correlation, and why are they correlated ?

Comment: Thanks for following up, sorry I think I phrased that wrong: X is not correlated with week, but I mean that each value of X for a given person is not the same for each week. Like the values of x for week 1,2,3 etc are different. They do not vary systematically with week, i.e. they are not correlated. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Richie OK, in that case you can go ahead and try fitting random intercepts for `week`. There may of course, but no variation at the `week` level, or the data may not support this additional random structure, in which case you can remove it.